# How to get rid of the submit button inner border in IE & Opera?

Tags: css

Here's a sample form:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Sample Form</title>
<style type="text/css">
input#send {width:80px; height:20px; padding:0; border:0;}
div {width:80px; height:20px; border: 1px solid green}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form name="input" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="user"> Name
<div><input id="send" type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The submit button gets a dotted border inside when focused.

Many thanks for any help!

Rain Lover

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want this CSS `{ outline : none; }`

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

If you change part of your page so it looks like this:

```
input#send {width:80px; height:20px; padding:0; border:0; outline: none;}
```

it will work. I just tested it and it works on my IE8.

Comment: The problem remains the same in IE6 and Opera11.

Comment: @RainLover: Looks like you found the answer here: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/web-page-design-1/how-get-rid-submit-button-inner-border-ie-opera-746520.html